# Getting negative DPI of a image in java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Getting negative imageXScale and imageYScale  for some of pdf's 
while converting pdf to image and finding its DPI.
Jar used is pdfbox1.8.8 and iText.

Found image Im0
position=602.64,451.08
size=837px,626px size=-212.59799mm,-159.131mm

Position which must be 0 has some value.
unable to detect the problem

Comment: What is your problem, why shouldn't those values be negative?

Comment: How can DPI of an image be in negative

Comment: I don't see any DPI values in your question text.

Comment: Does my answer explain the issue sufficiently?

Answer (score 1):

The OP mentions he uses *pdfbox1.8.8 and iText* but offers no further indication how he retrieves values from his PDF using either of these libraries.

Considering the words *imageXScale* and *imageYScale* and the position and size outputs, I would assume he has used the [PrintImageLocations PDFBox example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/2.0.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java).

### The meaning of the PrintImageLocations outputs

This sample does the following outputs for a bitmap image drawn somewhere on a page:

```
System.out.println("Found image [" + objectName.getName() + "]");
```

The name of the image resource

```
Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
float imageXScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorX();
float imageYScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorY();

// position in user space units. 1 unit = 1/72 inch at 72 dpi
System.out.println("position in PDF = " + ctmNew.getTranslateX() + ", " + ctmNew.getTranslateY() + " in user space units");
```

Position of the anchor point, i.e. where the original bottom left corner of the image is drawn on the page.

```
// raw size in pixels
System.out.println("raw image size  = " + imageWidth + ", " + imageHeight + " in pixels");
```

The original width and height of the image resource in pixels. Always non-negative.

```
// displayed size in user space units
System.out.println("displayed size  = " + imageXScale + ", " + imageYScale + " in user space units");
```

The width and height of the image as drawn on the page. Negative values may mean that the image resource is not drawn right and up from the anchor point but instead left and down.

```
// displayed size in inches at 72 dpi rendering
imageXScale /= 72;
imageYScale /= 72;
System.out.println("displayed size  = " + imageXScale + ", " + imageYScale + " in inches at 72 dpi rendering");
```

The width and height of the image as drawn on the page in inches assuming a user space unit width of 1/72nd inch, the default. Negative values may occur, see above.

```
// displayed size in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering
imageXScale *= 25.4;
imageYScale *= 25.4;
System.out.println("displayed size  = " + imageXScale + ", " + imageYScale + " in millimeters at 72 dpi rendering");
```

The width and height of the image as drawn on the page in mm assuming a user space unit width of 1/72nd inch, the default. Negative values may occur, see above.

Thus, negative values here have a meaning (a mirroring or 180° rotation) which makes no difference in respect to any DPI properties. So to calculate a DPI value, use the absolute values only, ignore the signs.

### Inconsistency in PDFBox

The x and y scaling factors used above are derived from the current transformation matrix like this:

```
/**
 * Returns the x-scaling factor of this matrix. This is calculated from the scale and shear.
 *
 * @return The x-scaling factor.
 */
public float getScalingFactorX()
{
    float xScale = single[0];

    /**
     * BM: if the trm is rotated, the calculation is a little more complicated
     *
     * The rotation matrix multiplied with the scaling matrix is:
     * (   x   0   0)    ( cos  sin  0)    ( x*cos x*sin   0)
     * (   0   y   0) *  (-sin  cos  0)  = (-y*sin y*cos   0)
     * (   0   0   1)    (   0    0  1)    (     0     0   1)
     *
     * So, if you want to deduce x from the matrix you take
     * M(0,0) = x*cos and M(0,1) = x*sin and use the theorem of Pythagoras
     *
     * sqrt(M(0,0)^2+M(0,1)^2) =
     * sqrt(x2*cos2+x2*sin2) =
     * sqrt(x2*(cos2+sin2)) = <- here is the trick cos2+sin2 is one
     * sqrt(x2) =
     * abs(x)
     */
    if( !(single[1]==0.0f && single[3]==0.0f) )
    {
        xScale = (float)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(single[0], 2)+
                                  Math.pow(single[1], 2));
    }
    return xScale;
}
```

*([Excerpt from Matrix.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/2.0.0/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/util/Matrix.java))*

While obviously someone did spend some thoughts on this (look at the comment!), the implementation is somewhat inconsistent:

- If there are non-zero values in `single[1]` or `single[3]`, the calculation in the `if` block results in a non-negative method result.
- For zero values in both `single[1]` and  `single[3]`, though, `single[0]` is returned as-is which may be negative.

A consistent implementation would either always remove the sign or always try to determine a meaningful sign

Furthermore the calculation is somewhat simplistic as it only considers transformation matrices which can be written as product of a scaling and a rotation. These are very common types but by far not all possible ones.